# Create unique id with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and I am trying to create an ID like **(MPC01)** to the database `id` field. It should be increment like MPC01 -> MPC02 -> MPC03 to MPC99

```
function get_main_prouduct_id(){
        $this->db->select(array("main_products_cat_id"));
        $this->db->order_by("main_products_cat_id","desc");
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $result=$this->db->get("tbl_main_products_category");
        $re="MPC05";
        $id=intval(substr($re,3));
        $id2="MPC$id";
        return $id;
    }
```

this is the code now I am using and it give me error

```
Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

How do I do changes this to make **MPC01** formant and increment its value

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with `insert` … which is what that error is referring too …

Comment: You need to look at the [Codeigniter Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html)

Comment: @BrettSantore I need to just create and id for that i have another function for `insert`.